# How calculate sum of only desire rows?

Tags: org-mode

Windows 10, Emacs 26.1

here my org table:

```
|   | Start date       | End date         | Task     | State     | Duration (hours) |
|---+------------------+------------------+----------+-----------+------------------|
| # | 15.08.2019 10:30 | 15.08.2019 12:00 | T-320    | Taken     |             1.50 |
| # | 15.08.2019 13:00 | 15.08.2019 14:00 | T-320    | Taken     |             1.00 |
| # | 15.08.2019 14:30 | 15.08.2019 18:00 | T-321    | Taken     |             3.50 |
| # | 16.08.2019 10:30 | 16.08.2019 12:00 | T-321    | Taken     |             1.50 |
| # | 16.08.2019 13:30 | 16.08.2019 15:30 | T-321    | Taken     |             2.00 |
| # | 16.08.2019 15:30 | 16.08.2019 18:00 | T-322    | Taken     |             2.50 |
| # | 28.08.2019 14:00 | 28.08.2019 17:00 | T-330    | Taken     |             3.00 |
| # | 28.08.2019 17:00 | 28.08.2019 18:00 | T-331    | Taken     |             1.00 |
| # | 29.08.2019 10:30 | 29.08.2019 15:00 | INIT-117 | Done      |             4.50 |
| # | 29.08.2019 15:30 | 29.08.2019 16:00 | FM-222   | Done      |             0.50 |
| # | 29.08.2019 16:00 | 29.08.2019 18:00 | T-331    | Postponed |             2.00 |
| # | 30.08.2019 10:30 | 30.08.2019 12:00 | INIT-121 | Taken     |             1.50 |
| # | 30.08.2019 13:30 | 30.08.2019 21:00 | INIT-121 | Taken     |             7.50 |
|---+------------------+------------------+----------+-----------+------------------|
|   |                  |                  |          |           |            32.00 |
#+TBLFM: $6=$3-$2;t::@>$6=vsum(@I..@II);%.2f 
#+TBLFM: $6=$3-$2;t::@>$6=vsum(@557..@564);%.2f
```

When I want to calculate sum of all rows in column `Duration` I use `M-x org-recalculate-table`

The result is `32.00`
Nice it's work fine.

But suppose I want to calculate sum only `1, 5, 7` rows. And I want do this WITHOUT delete rest rows.
The result must be `6.50`

```
|   | Start date       | End date         | Task  | State | Duration (hours) |
|---+------------------+------------------+-------+-------+------------------|
| # | 15.08.2019 10:30 | 15.08.2019 12:00 | T-320 | Taken |             1.50 |
| # | 16.08.2019 13:30 | 16.08.2019 15:30 | T-321 | Taken |             2.00 |
| # | 28.08.2019 14:00 | 28.08.2019 17:00 | T-330 | Taken |             3.00 |
|---+------------------+------------------+-------+-------+------------------|
|   |                  |                  |       |       |             6.50 |
#+TBLFM: $6=$3-$2;t::@>$6=vsum(@I..@II);%.2f 
#+TBLFM: $6=$3-$2;t::@>$6=vsum(@557..@564);%.2f
```

How I can do this without remove rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try the `orgtbl-aggregate` package available on Melpa. You will be able to compute partial sums of cells in a column depending on another column. Without changing your table.

For example you may aggregate rows with similar `State` values:

```
#+BEGIN: aggregate :table "atable" :cols "State vsum('Duration (hours)')"
| State     | vsum('Duration (hours)') |
|-----------+--------------------------|
| Taken     |                      25. |
| Done      |                       5. |
| Postponed |                       2. |
#+END:
```

If you want the global sum, just remove `State` in the aggregation specification:

```
#+BEGIN: aggregate :table "atable" :cols "vsum('Duration (hours)')"
| vsum('Duration (hours)') |
|--------------------------|
|                      32. |
#+END:
```

In your example, to select just rows `1,5,7` you would add a column to flag those rows:

```
#+name: atable
|   | Start date       | End date         | Task  | State | Duration (hours) | flag |
|---+------------------+------------------+-------+-------+------------------+------|
| # | 15.08.2019 10:30 | 15.08.2019 12:00 | T-320 | Taken |             1.50 | YES  |
| # | 15.08.2019 13:00 | 15.08.2019 14:00 | T-320 | Taken |             1.00 | no   |
...etc...

#+BEGIN: aggregate :table "atable" :cols "flag vsum('Duration (hours)')"
| flag | vsum('Duration (hours)') |
|------+--------------------------|
| YES  |                      6.5 |
| no   |                     25.5 |
#+END:
```

https://github.com/tbanel/orgaggregate/blob/master/README.org

Comment: Is it  possible to sum value in column "Duration" in all rows contain some text (e.g "T-321")? I don't want to add additional column like "flag"

Comment: This help me: aggregate :table "atable" :cols "Task vsum(Duration);f2" :cond(string= Task "T-321")

Comment: Right! With `:cond` you can add filtering on the input rows. Only rows for which the custom lisp expression return non-nil will be considered by Aggregate

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `calc` command [`subscr`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Extracting-Elements.html). It also works for sets of indices as the following eval in the `*scratch*` buffer shows:

```el
(calc-eval "subscr({1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6,7.7,8.8,9.9},{1,5,7})")
"{ 1.1,
  5.5,
  7.7 }"
```

Your table with the modified formula looks as follows.

```
|   | Start date       | End date         | Task     | State     | Duration (hours) |
|---+------------------+------------------+----------+-----------+------------------|
| # | 15.08.2019 10:30 | 15.08.2019 12:00 | T-320    | Taken     |             1.50 |
| # | 15.08.2019 13:00 | 15.08.2019 14:00 | T-320    | Taken     |             1.00 |
| # | 15.08.2019 14:30 | 15.08.2019 18:00 | T-321    | Taken     |             3.50 |
| # | 16.08.2019 10:30 | 16.08.2019 12:00 | T-321    | Taken     |             1.50 |
| # | 16.08.2019 13:30 | 16.08.2019 15:30 | T-321    | Taken     |             2.00 |
| # | 16.08.2019 15:30 | 16.08.2019 18:00 | T-322    | Taken     |             2.50 |
| # | 28.08.2019 14:00 | 28.08.2019 17:00 | T-330    | Taken     |             3.00 |
| # | 28.08.2019 17:00 | 28.08.2019 18:00 | T-331    | Taken     |             1.00 |
| # | 29.08.2019 10:30 | 29.08.2019 15:00 | INIT-117 | Done      |             4.50 |
| # | 29.08.2019 15:30 | 29.08.2019 16:00 | FM-222   | Done      |             0.50 |
| # | 29.08.2019 16:00 | 29.08.2019 18:00 | T-331    | Postponed |             2.00 |
| # | 30.08.2019 10:30 | 30.08.2019 12:00 | INIT-121 | Taken     |             1.50 |
| # | 30.08.2019 13:30 | 30.08.2019 21:00 | INIT-121 | Taken     |             7.50 |
|---+------------------+------------------+----------+-----------+------------------|
|   |                  |                  |          |           |              6.5 |
#+TBLFM: @>$6=vsum(subscr(@I$6..@II$6,{1,5,7}));%.2f
```

Comment: This formula also work: #+TBLFM: $6=$3-$2;t::@>$6=vsum(subscr(@I$6..@II$6,{1,5,7}));%.2f

Comment: @a_subscriber Ah, yes, I forgot to put the format specifier back. Corrected right now. Thanks for the notification.